# How can I run a script while http request is sent?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am building a website that will call a third-party web service. This web service is sometimes slow, however, and clients visiting the webpage aren't familiar with the loader on the browser tab. This results to them clicking, again and again, the search button that calls the web service and it gets never completely sent.

I was thinking of making an overlay page with a CSS loader right in the middle of the page so that it's more than obvious that something's loading and force them to wait. I tried researching how to run a script while an HTTP request is being sent, but didn't get any answers. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for your time.

The WiP website is https://b2b.a-link.gr/ (unfortunately a client username and password is required to access it) and the web service website is https://www.soft1.eu/. The web service has a database through which I pull out data to make searches on my website.

Comment: Just show the overlay *before* you make the HTTP request and hide it when it returns. You don't need to show it only while the request is being actually carried out.

Comment: how do I control it though? how can I start it and then terminate it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what confuses you. You'll surely have some click event being triggered, which will call a function. In that function you show the overlay, then make the http request, then when it returns you hide the overlay. If you shared some code it would have been simpler to give better suggestions for your particular case.

Comment: Show overlay, make AJAX request, hide overlay again inside callback that handles the result of the AJAX request …? What is complicated about that?

Comment: <?php foreach($brandmodeltypes as $search):?>
           <?php //print_r($search);?>
           <?php if ($ο++ > 10) break;?>
           <a href="/antallaktika/search?s=<?php echo search["search"];?>"><?php echo $search["search"];?></a>
           <?php endforeach;?>

That's the search button. Not so sure it helps (in this form) that's why I didn't share earlier.

Comment: @litzel in your question, please. It's unreadable like this.

Comment: Also, there's no AJAX in there, it's just a link.

Comment: Indeed, there is no AJAX in this web service call.

Comment: Well if no AJAX is involved, that means a normally submitted form? Then the current page gets _replaced_ with the new result page the server eventually returns - so hiding this overlay again is not even necessary. All you have to do then is to show it when the form gets submitted.

Comment: Yes, actually, on click or enter key press it shows a search result products page. So, if I get it right, you suggest I show the overlay on click/keypress and let it disappear on it's own when it moves to another web page?

Comment: @litzel yes, exactly